# Не удается отправить email через SMTP авторизацию

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, exim

На сервере №1 (1.1.1.1) настроен exim, создан почтовый ящик "info", email отправляются/доходят успешно. Но когда выполняю отправку с сервера №2 (2.2.2.2), используя логин/пароль для авторизации, почтовый сервер не пропускает письмо, ошибка:

> H=mailer.server2.com (1.1.1.1) [2.2.2.2] rejected MAIL : Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)

1. почему HELO не верный? в логе видно, что отправляется `H=mailer.server2.com`
2. как настроить разрешение для отправки с любым HELO с сервера №2 (2.2.2.2)?

На серверах установлена ubuntu.

**Решение**

1. Не смотря на сообщение в логе, по факту сервер высылал HELO в виде ip-адреса сервера №1. В заголовке письма было:

   > helo=1.1.1.1

   А правильно должно быть:

   > mail.server1.com
2. Настройки разрешения в

   > /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template

   [image: /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template]

   Разумеется, для боевой версии правила надо настроить на конкретные ip адреса.

**Настройка правильного HELO**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в какой ip-адрес резолвится имя `mailer.server2.com` на том и на другом компьютере?

Comment: как это можно проверить?

Comment: например: `$ host имя-или-ip-адрес`.

Comment: на обоих серверах 130.111.109.77.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mailer.server2.com.

Comment: порылся в интернетах. возможно, на первый ваш вопрос ответ должен быть: неправильно аутентифицируетесь.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. почему HELO не верный?

похоже на неправильную аутентификацию.

---

> 2. как настроить разрешение для отправки с любым HELO с сервера №2

на самом этом сервере? никак. согласно [rfc821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821):

> In the HELO command the host sending the command identifies
> itself; the command may be interpreted as saying "Hello, I am
> ".

вольный перевод:

> с помощью команды helo компьютер отсылает информацию, идентифицирующую его самого. эту команду можно интерпретировать как «привет! меня зовут так-то».

т.е., если подключение происходит с ip-адреса, резолвящегося в *имя1*, а представляется компьютер как *имя2*, то, вероятно, этот компьютер пытается ввести вас в заблуждение.